# How do I access BlockBlobClient in Azure Storage JavaScript client library for browsers?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk, azure-node-sdk

I'm attempting to use BlockBlobClient in a browser page to upload a file using a server-supplied sastoken / URL, similar to this C# code:

```
            var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(assetUploadUrl));
            blob.UploadFromFile(FilePath, null, new BlobRequestOptions {RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry()});
```

Although the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest) suggest BlockBlobClient is available in @azure/storage-blob and should be able to upload browser data from an input[type=file] element using [uploadBrowserData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadbrowserdata-blob---arraybuffer---arraybufferview--blockblobparalleluploadoptions-), I can find no reference to BlockBlobClient in the browser [library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/browser) source. I looked into modifying the browserify export scripts but I can't find any references in the main [package](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) source either. Also the example code suggests that using @azure/storage-blog gives you a BlobServiceClient by default:

```js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
```

Is BlockBlobClient actually available in the JavaScript client library?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've figured this out, I need to use the [Azure Storage client library for JavaScript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage#azure-storage-client-library-for-javascript), there's even a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/browserSamples/largeFileUploads.js) of doing exactly what I need to do. Now I just need to figure out how to bundle npm package files for use in Razor pages.